# Is there some ways to get the features of a curve?

Tags: curve-fitting, bezier, curve, curves

Now, I have a group of data which describes objects' access counts per seconds. According to these data I get the curves of every object as follows.
[image]

So I wander how can I get the features of every curve.

For **curve A**, there is a sharp change between phase1 and phase2, but in the whole lifetime the curve A is **periodically stable**.

For **curve B**, there is a **sharp change** between phase1 and phase2, and in the whole lifetime this curve is not stable.

On the other hand, the **curve c** is ALWAYS **stable** in the whole lifetime.

In brief, I need to **classify these curve** to **stabilization**, **periodical stabilization** and **sharp change**. Moreover, for periodical stabilization I need to get the period, and for sharp change, I need to know the sharp change occurred in which phase.

***************classes description********************

**stabilization** means the values of the curve are always around a certain value without great change. The **curve C** is a rough description.

**periodical stabilization** means the values of the curve have great change between two phase, and this kind of change is periodical. The **curve A** is a rough description.

**sharp change** means the values of the curve have great change between two phase and this kind of change is not repetitive. The **curve B** is a rough description.

Comment: No idea what you mean with "stable". And how do you relate the curves A, B and C to the "classes"  stabilization, periodical stabilization and sharp change ??

Comment: This has nothing to do with image processing, you should improve the tags.